# How do I view and pull off videos from my iCloud?

Tags: itunes, icloud, video

A while back, when I moved to a new town and didn't have my hard drive with me, I was running out of room on my Mac (I collect a lot of movies and television series), so I moved a television series that I didn't watch all that often into my iCloud (or so I thought).  I deleted it from my Macbook library, but only because iTunes gave me the impression (via warning alerts) that despite me deleting them, they would still be stored in iCloud.  Three months later, after cleaning out my Mac, I want to watch the stored series again, but now I have no idea how to access my iCloud storage or how to pull files out of it.  I've tried looking for answers online, but I keep getting very vague information regarding mostly how to use iCloud rather than how to access it.  Can someone please help me.  Please be as detailed as possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can download your purchased series again via iTunes. Open the iTunes Store and go to the "Purchased" section, select the content type and then click the cloud icon next to the item you want to download.

See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519
(keyword: iTunes in the cloud)